# How did this minor edit get through, and why is there no rollback link?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, character-limit

I'm referring to [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15149190/revisions) on this question. The user moved a single apostrophe; but I thought there was a minimum 6 character limit on edits?

Also, where has the rollback link gone?

[image: a]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The user moved a single apostrophe; but I thought there was a minimum 6 character limit on edits?

Users will full edit privileges are not limited to the 6 characters.

> Also, where has the rollback link gone?

Only users with full edit privileges can conduct rollbacks on other people's posts. Users under the threshold can only conduct rollbacks on their own posts. Otherwise, they have to manually undo the edits.

> FYI, the apostrophe was in the correct position to begin with, at r2 (look it up if you care).

No, it wasn't. You only append the apostrophe to the end of the word if the "s" was part of the word to begin with, like with the word "compass."

> The compass' needle pointed North.

Comment: And note that the rollback link is of course only present on revisions you can roll back to. Therefore it's not present on the revision header shown.

Comment: @Servy: AFAIK "people" is already a plural, and "peoples" is only used to refer to a nation or race, but that's a question for EL&L.

Comment: An example use of referring to the possessive of multiple groups, the book titled [Other Peoples' Myths: The Cave of Echoes](http://www.amazon.com/Other-Peoples-Myths-Cave-Echoes/dp/0226618579/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1362519863&sr=8-1&keywords=other+peoples%27+myths)